# Postgresql Copy Function from the Server Computer to the Client Computer

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-copy

I would like to import a table from the server computer into a Client computer using the copy command. I know this is a recurring issue for users, but I have not been able to get an answer to this particular one and it's also a different scenario, and I believe this to be common.

I used a copy command to copy a Table from the server to the client computer using the code below:

```
COPY (Select * from Table_Name) TO 'C:\somedirectory\file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

However, I got the following

> ERROR: relative path not allowed for COPY to file

My question is: How do I use the correct COPY command to copy from the server computer to the client computer in Postgres.

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if your user has read/write access to the destination folder.
2. This is one thread I found, see if it helps

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158466/relative-path-for-psql-copy-file
https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1116997

3. Try with network through access using client public IP.

Answer (score 0):

> *How do I use the correct COPY command to copy from the server computer to the client computer in Postgres*

You simply can't.

Which is clearly stated [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL **server** to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the **name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server**

(emphasis mine)

You need to use `psql`'s `\copy` command or any other export tool that works on the client side.